# Adding Blank Space in the List of Figures, List of Tables, and Table of Contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm learning LaTeX to typeset some documents. I hope someone here could help me.

How do I go on adding a space in the List of Figures and List of Tables.

I'm using \listoffigures and \listoftables to generate these two pages.

Here is how the List of Tables page looks like: [image]

As you can see the title "LIST OF TABLES" is almost aligned to the page number x.

What I want is to have something that looks like this:
[image]

I want to add several spaces between the page number and the title. I want to do this for the List of Figures page and the List of Tables page and for the Table of Contents as well.

I hope someone could help. Thank you!

Comment: Try \makeatletter \def\@pnumwidth}{3em} \makeatother.

Comment: we need a mwe of you code `\documentclass{...}......\end{document}`

Comment: I think i have seen this before. This is some weird template where all the chapter titles are dancing around like crazy pidgeons. Can you give a pointer to the template so i can get it on my TODO-List?

Answer (score 1):

I am using tocloft package.

```
% Add this to your preamble
\usepackage{tocloft} % this package manipulates toc, lot, lof

 % adding 1in vertical space in ToC, LoF and LoT
 % change to the value 1in in to anything you like
 % greater the value greater the space between page number and title
 \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{1in}
 \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{1in}
 \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{1in}
```